# How to implement a submethod in a Python-class?

Tags: python, class, methods

I appologize, if I didn't express my self clearly. What I want to do is this:

```
class someClass(object):
    def aMethod(self, argument):
        return some_data #for example a list or a more complex datastructure
    def aMethod_max(self, argument):
        var = self.aMethod(argument)
        #do someting with var
        return altered_var
```

or I could do:

```
    def aMethod(self, argument):
        self.someVar = some_data
        return some_data #for example a list or a more complex datastructure
    def aMethod_max(self, argument):
        if not hasattr(self, someVar):
            self.aMethod(argument)        
        #do someting with self.var
        return altered_var
```

But I considered this too complicated and hoped for a more elegant solution. I hope that it's clear now, what I want to accomplish.

Therefore I phantasized about something like in the following paragraph.

```
class someClass(object):
    someMethod(self):
        #doSomething
        return result
    subMethod(self):
        #doSomething with the result of someMethod

Foo = someClass()
Foo.someMethod.subMethod()
```

or if someMethod has an argument something like

```
Foo.someMethod(argument).subMethod()
```

How would I do something like this in python?

EDIT: or like this?

```
subMethod(self):
    var = self.someMethod()
    return doSomething(var)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compare the existing solutions already given in your question (e.g. the ones you call "complicated" and "inelegant") with your proposed alternative.

The existing solutions mean you will be able to write:

```
foo.subMethod() # foo.someMethod() is called internally
```

but your proposed alternative means you have to write:

```
foo.someMethod().subMethod()
```

which is obviously worse.

On the other hand, if `subMethod` has to be able to modify the result of *any* method, rather than just `someMethod`, then the existing solutions would mean you have to write:

```
foo.subMethod(foo.anyMethod())
```

with the only disadvantage here being that you have to type `foo` twice, as opposed to once.

Conclusion: on the whole, the existing solutions are less complicated and inelegant than your proposed alternative - so stick with the existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) when the result of someMethod is an instance of someClass.

Simple example:

```
>>> class someClass:
...   def someMethod(self):
...     return self
...   def subMethod(self):
...     return self.__class__
... 
>>> x=someClass()
>>> x
<__main__.someClass instance at 0x2aaaaab30d40>
>>> x.someMethod().subMethod()
<class __main__.someClass at 0x2aaaaab31050>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. The second method should be able to do something with the result of the first method. For example: the first method returns a list and the second method returns a result based on the input from the first method. I hope this explains it in a better way.

Comment: @Randomtheories Then the answer is no. It's not possible to do what you describe, because you can only chain methods of the returned object. If you return a list, you can chain list methods. If you return a string, you can chain string methods. Unless `someMethod` returns a `someClass` instance, `subMethod` won't be available to chain.

Comment: @kojiro seems to me that you could track changes to the variable by stashing results in the class instance, while still returning self (thus maintaining the fluent interface). Am I missing something? Regardless, this seems like a poor API design and should probably be revised.

Comment: @OwenNelson well, I thought about possible responses along those lines, as well as having the object subclass `list` and store the list values themselves. It could be *made to work* with careful planning, but the *only* way to do what OP asked for is to have every chainable method return `self` (or another instance of the same class).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar using decorators:

```
def on_result(f):
    def decorated(self,other,*args,**kwargs):
        result = getattr(self,other)(*args,**kwargs)
        return f(result)
    return decorated
```

Usage:

```
class someClass(object):
    def someMethod(self,x,y):
        #doSomething
        result = [1,2,3,x,y] # example
        return result
    @on_result
    def subMethod(self):
        #doSomething with the result of someMethod
        print self # example

Foo = someClass()
Foo.subMethod("someMethod",4,5)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you see, the first argument is the name of the method to be chained, and the remaining ones will be passed to it, no matter what its signature is.

EDIT: on second thought, this is rather pointless, since you could always use

```
Foo.submethod(Foo.someMethod(4,5))...
```

Maybe I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve. Does the subMethod have to be linked to a **specific** method only? Or maybe it's the syntatic form

```
a.b().c()
```

that's important to you? (in that case, see kojiro's answer)

Comment: The question is about linking the argument of the subMethod to the result of someMethod. By the way: shouldn't it be Foo.submethod(Foo.someMethod(4, 5))? Thank you for you thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding it right, but perhaps you mean this:

```
Foo.subMethod(Foo.someMethod())
```

This passes the result of someMethod() to subMethod(). You'd have to change your current definition of subMethod() to accept the result of someMethod().

Comment: Yes, that's what's it all about. I wanted to know if there are other methods to achieve this. And maybe to define subMethod specifically to only take results of someMethod as an argument. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

From the feedback so far, I understand that *subMethod* will link **only** to *someMethod*, right? Maybe you can achieve this combining a decorator with a closure:

```
def on_result(other):
    def decorator(f):
        def decorated(self,*a1,**k1):
            def closure(*a2,**k2):
                return f(self,getattr(self,other)(*a1,**k1),*a2,**k2)
            return closure
        return decorated
    return decorator

class someClass(object):
    def someMethod(self,a,b):
        return [a,2*b]
    @on_result('someMethod')
    def subMethod(self,result,c,d):
        result.extend([3*c,4*d])
        return result

Foo = someClass()
print Foo.subMethod(1,2)(3,4) # prints [1,4,9,16]
```

The decorator is kinda "ugly", but once written it's usage is quite elegant IMHO (plus, there are no contraints in the signature of either method).

Note: I'm using Python 2.5 and this is the only way I know of writing decorators that take arguments. There's probably a better way, but I'm too lazy to look it up right now...